# dpkg --get-selections | grep hold not working in 16.04

Tags: package-management, grep, phpmyadmin

I am getting this error

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: ttf-dejavu-core but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: mysql-client
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

But i cannot see what is the broken packages

after `apt policy ttf-dejavu-core`

I got this `ttf-dejavu-core:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.33-2ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.33-2ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise/main i386 Packages`

after running `sudo apt install -f`

I got this lines `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

After running `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` I get these lines in my terminal

`      root@mohsin:~# cat /etc/apt/sources.list
       #############################################################
       ################### OFFICIAL UBUNTU REPOS ###################
      #############################################################

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted 
universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted 
universe multiverse

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main 
restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main 
restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main 
restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-security main 
restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main 
restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main 
 restricted universe multiverse
```

Ubuntu Partner Repo

deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

Ubuntu Extras Repo

deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe main
`

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? Run `sudo apt install -f`.

Comment: @Pilot6 my ubuntu versioon is 16.04. After running `sudo apt install -f` I got this `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: What command gives you the output ypu posted in the question? Is `universe` repo enabled? Did you ever run `sudo apt update`?

Comment: @Pilot6 I want to install `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext` in my 16.04 linux but it giving me error this lines `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 phpmyadmin : Depends: ttf-dejavu-core but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: mysql-client
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`  I tried to install `mysql-client` but same error `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: Please post additional information TO YOUR QUESTION using [edit] link. Please post output of `apt policy ttf-dejavu-core` there.

Comment: @Pilot6 did changes please have a look

Comment: How about running `sudo apt install ttf-dejavu-core`?

Comment: Hey @Pilot6 first I run `sudo apt install ttf-dejavu-core` this works fine. then i run `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext` then i got these error `Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2.2-bin_2.2.22-1ubuntu1.11_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2.2-common_2.2.22-1ubuntu1.11_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/apache2-mpm-prefork_2.2.22-1ubuntu1.11_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

apt-get autoremove

apt-get update

If you get broken help packages error while apt-get update, check in /etc/apt/sources.list if updates are enabled or not.

Comment: could you explain why this should do any difference ?

Comment: @newbie this lines didn't solve the error  `apt-get autoremove

apt-get update` . how to check in this file **sources.list**  updates are enabled or not ?

Comment: @ Soren AUpdates  might  contain the updated packages you need.
"Important security updates (...)". Updates that fix security vulnerabilities. They are managed by the Ubuntu Security Team and are designed to change the behavior of the package as little as possible 
"Recommended updates (...)". Updates for serious bugs other than security vulnerabilities.

Comment: @Soren A "Unsupported updates (...)". New versions of packages which have been backported to an older release. Packages may contain new features, may introduce new interfaces, and bugs. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu#Updates_Tab
I once ran into held broken packages while running apt-get update and uncommenting update repository helped me out

Comment: @Mohsin /etc/apt has file named as sources.list. 
cat sources.list
There might be repos having "updates" at the end. Check if they are commented out.

Comment: @newbie I can see three file here at apt folder 1. sources.list 2. sources.list.save 3. trusted.gpg. In sources.list nothing is commented out..

Comment: @Mohsin Run this command : cat sources.list.
You will see a number of repos, like shown below====# 
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
#deb-src http://us-east-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
. Now, check for repos that have updates in tail. Or post the output of cat /etc/apt/sources.list in question

Comment: @newbie please have a look at my question I just added the output at bottom of my question thank u new bie

Comment: @Mohsin Please paste output of lsb_release -a